# vstack along with filling empty cells

Tags: numpy

I have three arrays with sizes 5X5 and 5X4 alternatively.

That is, the list of array sizes are

5X5

5X4

5X5

If I use vstack, it shows error because of size incompatibility.

Is there any possibility to use vstack that automatically fills the extra column for second matrix?

Comment: No.  `vstack` does not do padding.  There are ways of padding arrays, but `vstack` alone is not enough.

Comment: Search [numpy] and 'padding'